# Techni-Higgs Particle

Tags: particle-physics, higgs

I read online that a professor from Denmark alleged that the particle that was found in Cern is not necessarily Higgs Boson, it has many characteristics that match with the "god particle" , but it could rather be a techni-higgs particle. So what is a techni-Higgs particle? Is his suggestion founded?

Comment: I suggest you read about Technicolor theories. They are theories beyond the standard model which are used to explain Electroweak Symmetry Breaking, i.e. the process via which the weak force carrier particles, (the W and Z bosons) acquire mass!

Comment: Any recommendation for online study?

Comment: No, sorry. You could start with the Wikipedia page on Technicolor theories, because that was the only thing I found. (Wikipedia tends to have, umm, inaccurate content so beware of that.)